# ConcurrentMap on demand loading java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm working on an on demand cache that needs to be thread-safe. I have data for about 30K + items (in one file) that I want to obtain only when needed for my mult-threaded game. However I'm not sure if my approach is how ConcurrentMap's computeIfAbsent is supposed to be used, and if it isn't what alternative is there for me to lazily load contents from a single file without worrying about threading issues? I want to avoid locking if the object exists in my map, which I've read using CHM does on reads.

I've pre-cached file names (which are IDs) that I want to load to ensure they exist to avoid constant checking via the `headers` hash map. The `headers` map is read-only and will only be loaded once upon starting of my program.

this is what I've done:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, ItemData> items = new ConcurentHashMap<>();
private static final HashMap<Integer, Byte> headers = new HashMap<>(); // pre loaded file names to avoid checking if file exists

public static ItemData getItem(int itemID) {
   var item = items.get(itemID);
   if (item != null) {
      return item;
   }
   // if item doesn't exist in map, check if it exists in file on disk
   if (!headers.containsKey(itemID)) {
      return null;
   }
   // if item exists in file add it to cache
   return items.computeIfAbsent(itemID, k -> {
            try (var dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("item.bin"))) {
                var data = new ItemData(itemID);
                data.load(dis); // obtains only data for one item
                return item;
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // ommited for brevity. logging goes here.
               return null;
            }
        });
}
```

**Update:** Pre-loading isn't an option for me, I agree doing that would solve threading-issues as it will only be read-only. But my game assets combined have a total size of over 2GB. I don't want to load everything during start up as some items in the files may never be used. Thus I'm looking for an approach to load them only when needed.

Comment: 30k is not that many.  Unless the objects take up a lot of memory, you should try just loading them all.  Then if you see performance problems, try to trouble shoot where the problem is.  Odds are it won't be where you are thinking.

Comment: CHM doesn't lock (these days).  But @markspace is probably right: 30K is not a lot of things, and loading them all up front is probably most practical.

Comment: Other commentary: 1) I don't like how you swallow an `IOException` and return `null`, that seems like a big potential problem. 2)  I don't think this is thread safe.  There's no synchronization between checking to see if an item exits and loading a new item.  Any number of threads could attempt to load the same item from disk, either causing performance problems or loading the dame item into `data` multiple times.

Comment: I can't pre-load all of this because they do take a lot of memory and I want to conserve as much as I can, as some of these items may never be used. 30k items was just for one item type, I have many other items that I want to load on demand.

Comment: I'm also checking if item exists in the file via the headers map, this map is cached on program start up and never modified. So that shouldn't require synchronization?

Comment: "Conserve as much [memory] as I can" doesn't feel like the right approach.  *The root of all evil is premature optimization.*  Do you know how much memory these objects would take?  Whats the number?  (That's a [famous quote by Donald Knuth](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) btw.)

Comment: Combined all data files is equivalent to 2GB+, if pre-loading was an option for me I would do it. But out of these thousand and thousands of items, some may never see the day of light. So pre-loading doesn't make sense to me, is there no viable alternative?

Comment: No, there certainly is, and ConcurrentHashMap isn't a bad place to start -- but if that's an issue, you'll also need to think about _unloading_ values when you have too many in your solution.  Consider something like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Comment: Came here to recommend Caffeine, specifically `AsyncLoadingCache`.

Comment: I'm looking for a native approach to this without using external libs like Caffeine.

Comment: @LouisWasserman not only “these days”, CHM never did locking on get. From [the very first version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): “*Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block*”…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> I want to avoid locking if the object exists in my map, which I've read using CHM does on reads.

I don’t know where you read that but it’s definitely wrong. It’s not even an outdated statement as even [the very first version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) specifies:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block…

The general structure of your approach is fine. In case of concurrent first time accesses for a key, it’s possible that multiple threads pass the first check but only one will do the actual retrieval in `computeIfAbsent` and all of them will use the result. Subsequent accesses to an already loaded item may benefit from the first plain `get` access.

There’s still something to improve.

```java
return items.computeIfAbsent(itemID, k -> {
    try (var dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("item.bin"))) {
        var data = new ItemData(k);
        data.load(dis); // obtains only data for one item
        return item;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // may still do logging here
       throw new UncheckIOException(e);
    }
});
```

First, while it’s a good approach to do logging (which you omitted for brevity), returning `null` and forcing the calling code to deal with `null` is not a good idea. You already have the `headers.containsKey(…)` check that tells us that the resource is supposed to be there, so the application likely has no way to deal with the absence, so we’re talking about an exceptional situation.

Further, you can use the `k` parameter passed to the function rather than accessing `itemID` from the surrounding scope. Limiting access scopes is not only cleaner, in this case, it turns the lambda expression into a non-capturing one, which means that it doesn’t require to create a new object each time, that would otherwise be needed to hold the captured value.

---

If you really read the same `item.bin` file for all `ItemData`, you may consider using memory mapped I/O to share the data, instead of reading it with a `DataInputStream`. The `ByteBuffer` representation of a memory mapped file offers almost the same methods to get compound items, it even supports little endian processing that `DataInputStream` doesn’t support.

Comment: Is the first `get` statement also fine? since when It reaches computeIfAbsent, it's calling `get` again. would just doing a return on `computeIfAbsent` and moving the `headers.containsKey()` check inside the lambda function before I create the ItemData object be a more cleaner approach?

Comment: Both approaches would work, but it’s an implementation detail whether `computeIfAbsent` does a lock-free probe first, to only lock when the key is absent. So, doing a definitely lock free `get` attempt first, ensures that subsequent queries for an already loaded element are definitely lock free. It also makes it obvious to the reader of the code that a lock free attempt is made first. This assumes a use case where there is one (or a few concurrent) first query for a key, followed by several subsequent queries for the same key which will benefit from the lock free read.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with my original approach then :).